# Google Maps API - Google Maps doesn't load fully in a Twitter-Bootstrap 3 column

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I've got a map loaded with Google JavaScript API and it does not load fully when initialized. I know that this problem is common, but none of the available solutions helped me.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDWTQpi0GTmb6hoIjbBlcGYfZLAkaDmqLI">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;

    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="tabContactMap">
        <div id="map-canvas">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

LESS (should be easily readable for people who know CSS, works similarly):

```
.tabContactMap {
    height:500px;
    #map-canvas {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    }
}

html, body, .row, .col-xs-12 { height: 100% }
```

What I get:
[image: Screenshot]

What can I do to make it work properly? I tried all of available solutions and it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am unable to comment, I will just post this as an answer.

I tried recreating this issue using the provided code in Chrome and Firefox and it seems to work just fine. Since the map-canvas has a height and width and it's parent has a fixed height as well, I don't see why this could be happening. It could also just be a network issue.

Works fine on JSbin as well:
Link: http://jsbin.com/moqeyumane

Comment: It seems that the map is loading properly when outside of any row or column, but it's controlls are all messed up really badly. They're all over the map.

Comment: Can you create a jsib or jsfiddle demonstrating this issue? , that would be helpful.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to update the situation. I managed to solve this problem. I changed the moment in which my map is initialized and then called a resize when clicking on a button that renders this map visible.